# CMake + CPack: Install entire directory (including subfolders)

Tags: cmake, cpack

I'm trying to create an installation package with CMake and CPack. Everything works fine, but I would like to reduce the amount of code drastically by copying my resources folder entirely with one call instead of one for every subfolder.

So far, I do component wise installation the following way:

```
set(RESOURCES_CALIBRATION_DIR resources/calibration)
file(GLOB RESOURCES_CALIBRATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${RESOURCES_CALIBRATION_DIR}/*")
install(FILES ${RESOURCES_CALIBRATION} DESTINATION ${RESOURCES_CALIBRATION_DIR} COMPONENT ResourcesCalibration)

set(RESOURCES_CURSORS_DIR resources/cursors)
file(GLOB RESOURCES_CURSORS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${RESOURCES_CURSORS_DIR}/*")
install(FILES ${RESOURCES_CURSORS} DESTINATION ${RESOURCES_CURSORS_DIR} COMPONENT ResourcesCursors)

...
    ... (repeat for every folder of my resources folder)

set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL applications ResourcesCalibration ResourcesCursors ...)
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_RESOURCESCALIBRATION_GROUP "resources")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_RESOURCESCURSORS_GROUP "resources")
...
    ...
```

Is there a clean way to copy / install the entire resources folder including all subfolders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command flow `install(DIRECTORY)` exists specifically for installing directory with its subdirectories and files.

```
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/
        DESTINATION resources
        COMPONENT ResourcesCursors)
```

or even

```
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/resources
        DESTINATION .
        COMPONENT ResourcesCursors)
```

will copy `resource` directory in the source tree to the installation directory. See [documentation on install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) for more info.